# Is it possible to resize catalog image for only one product in magento?

Tags: magento2, catalog

I want to resize only one catalog product images. Is it possible in magento2?

I already know the command for resizing catalog image:

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

but i want to do this for only one product images

Comment: using command or programmatically ?

Comment: any way !! but i  got the solution

Comment: How did you resize for only 1 product? could you share your answer @Rutvee Sojitra

Comment: Downvote. Happy you figured it out, but don't be so selfish to not share how....

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have any command line. So you have to build the command yourself.

Take look on `Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize::resizeFromThemes`

Comment: unable to find resizeFromThemes in Imageresize

Answer (score 0):

**Try This in Block File :-**

```
       protected $_filesystem ;
       protected $_imageFactory;
       public function __construct(            
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
            \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         
            ){         
                 $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
                 $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;         
            }

        public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
        {
            $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;
            if (!file_exists($absolutePath)) return false;
            $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;
            if (!file_exists($imageResized)) {

                $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
                $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
                $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
                $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
                $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
                $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
                $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
                //destination folder                
                $destination = $imageResized ;    
                //save image      
                $imageResize->save($destination);         
            } 
            $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
            return $resizedURL;
      }
```